# Hidden geometry reapears in weight paint mode

Tags: mesh, rigging, weight-painting

I am trying to weight paint my model. To make things easier I have already hidden most of my character. However no matter what I do, the face mesh always unhides itself when I enter  weight paint mode. I have most of my character parts divided into vertex groups, though I cant see how could that affect just the face to unhide itself.

I also tried selecting the face in weight paint mode with paint mask option selected and hide it this way. This does work, but as soon as I go to paint over the mesh the face reappears again.

Not sure if I am doing something wrong or if this is a bug.

[image]

Comment: try pressing <kbd>v</kbd> in weight paint mode?

Comment: Nope that doesn't work either...

Comment: maybe it's a bug, what Blender version are you using?

Comment: Blender version: 2.92

Comment: Yup its a bug. I installed Blender 2.82 and it works perfectly there. I guess I will be doing my weight painting there and then switch to the newer one later on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yup its a bug. I installed Blender 2.82 and it works perfectly there. I guess I will be doing my weight painting there and then switch to the newer one later on.

Comment: In case someone stumbles on this question with the newer version, this is still present in Blender 3.0, unfortunately.